# Getting really bad accuracy from CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm using CLLocationManager to get users location.

I want to get a single location update.

My problem is that I'm getting really bad `horizontalAccuracy`

> location is %@ <+xx.xxxxxx,+yy.yyyyyyy> +/- 3881.91m
>
> verticalAccuracy: 65.4401861912846, horizontalAccuracy: 3881.90892434957

Code:

```
fileprivate lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    return manager
}()

override init() {
    super.init()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else {
        return
    }
    
    let verticalAccuracy =  mostRecentLocation.verticalAccuracy
    let horizontalAccuracy = mostRecentLocation.horizontalAccuracy
    
    print("location is %@", mostRecentLocation)
    print("verticalAccuracy: \(verticalAccuracy), horizontalAccuracy:\(horizontalAccuracy)")
}
```

Any suggestions why is this happening?
I'm in a room next to a window so i except to get bad accuracy but not that bad.

Thanks

---

I'm getting ridiculous results.

I got horizontalAccuracy of 15,000 m.

When i go out doors it works great but in doors should not be as bad as this.

Using Cellular triangulation and wifi should give a lot better results.

---

after 20 minutes i started to get good results of +- 50 m accuracy in doors.

Comment: Where are you testing the app? Near Window is not a good option.

Comment: @Apurv, why not? i'm not expecting to get the best results but 4km accuracy is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add a condition to make sure that you will just be using a location that have a better accuracy. On my case I use 20 as the desired horizontal accuracy on below example.

Example:

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

         locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

         if locations.last!.horizontalAccuracy < 20 {
            //Only use location that enters here
         }
         else {
            //If the accuracy is not met then start updating location again and if possible increase more the accuracy (use kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation if you really need it). Make sure that you use the desired accuracy and filter properly to avoid draining battery.
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I always have found that when you first start location updates, the first few readings are quite poor, and then the accuracy improves as the GPS settles down.

What I do is to first check if the timestamp on the location is more than a few seconds old. If it is, I discard it. (Not sure if recent OS versions still send "stale" GPS readings, but the system used to give you a location from the last time the GPS was powered up, sometimes several **hours** old.)

Once I get current locations, I check the accuracy, and discard any location updates who's accuracy reading is too poor. Only when I get a reading that's good enough do I use it (and stop location updates in your case, since you only want 1 update.)

Bear in mind that it can take 30 seconds (or more) for the GPS to settle down, and in an area with poor GPS signal, you may never get a good enough reading.

Comment: I left the location running for 15 minutes and still getting the same bad results

Comment: You. Can't test this indoors. You have to add logging and take a phone outside to open sky with no tall buildings or trees blocking the GPS signal.

Comment: i know its spouse to work better out doors but the results are ridicules,
4 km accuracy.
In doors should give a lot better results using cellular/wifi.

Comment: If you're in a metal frame building you might not get a reading at all.